# Extract text from tuples

Tags: python, nlp, entity, text-extraction

I am a beginner. How can I extract certain text from a tuple or list in this example?

Example:

```
(<QueryEntity 'example_entity' ('example_entity_type') 
char: [somechar-somechar], tok: [sometok-sometok]>,)
```

I want to extract `example_entity` and `example_entity_type` from the tuple. I tried converting to a list and still get errors about `QueryEntity`.

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: add what you have tried so far.

Comment: I think your tuple doesn't contain a string object but some other type of object (`QueryEntity`).  The standard Python print statement displays a tuple containing a string like this: `('Hello',)`.  Your example doesn't have the quotation marks in the expected place for a string object.

Comment: @BemwaMalak The didn't try much because I couldn't even find anything that I thought applied to my situation but here is what I thought modeled I wanted:
```variable = (<QueryEntity 'example_entity' ('example_entity_type') char: [somechar-somechar], tok: [sometok-sometok]>,)
found = re.search('Entity \'(.+?)\'', variable).group(1)```
I got a ```TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object``` error in search.

Comment: @PaulCornelius My example is the only type of output I can get. Would there be a way to extract those specific pieces of text from this ```QueryEntity``` object in that case?

Comment: You need to find out what a QueryEntity object actually is and what it does.  It must come from some other piece of code.  There should be documentation somewhere describing what functions and variables it has.  Without that information you have no reliable way of getting the data you want.